# jQuery multiselect dropdown with close button for selected items

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

Basically I want something like this. What are the ready-made options for me? Is there any proper short name for this kind of widget?

[image: http://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/225116342/components.PNG?version=1&modificationDate=1286851639207]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost like your given example:

[jQuery MultiSelect Plugin](http://wilkerlucio.github.com/jquery-multiselect/)

Answer (score 2):

You may want this http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/.
Or this http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html.